# c++ cout a math function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

You `cin` a value to the variable `f`. `f` could be something like:

```
pow(5.957,-X*X*X*X)-cos(X*X) +20*sin(X*X)
```

or some other complicated math function. I also tried to declare it directly as such.

```
f = pow(5.957,-X*X*X*X)-cos(X*X) +20*sin(X*X);
std::cout << "Bisection method on function,  f = " << f << " "<<std::endl;
```

The output is on both MinGW and VS2010:

```
f = nan
```

How do I get cout to print f on the screen?

I declared f as such

```
double F(double X) { double f; f =  pow(5.957,-X*X*X*X)-cos(X*X) +20*sin(X*X); return f; }
```

I'm basically writing a C++ program to perform different numerical methods for finding roots on the function: bisection, Monte Carlo, Newtwon's method etc. Those work, but I want to display the function to the user after he types it in, and it just shows up as NaN.

Comment: What's the type of `f`? What values of `X` have you tried this with? What would you expect the value of `f` to be, given those values?

Comment: What is the value of X before you start? What was the value you were expecting as output?

Comment: nan means not a number, meaning there is an error somewhere.

Comment: Did you miss the 'pow' in the second expression? "(a,b)" is a valid C expression, so be careful.

Comment: From your question it sounds like `f` could literally be an equation someone typed in.

Comment: @Michael Don't add `pow` to the code if it wasn't there. That could have been his problem as @user48956 mentioned.

Comment: @quasiverse, point taken. I'd assumed that was static code, and since his code couldn't compile as written, I thought it was a copy/paste error. But birryee's comment makes more sense.

Comment: user, post a short but complete program that illustrates the problem. Include how you set all variables, and how you're printing them out. We're all guessing at what you're actually running.

Comment: I just typed in a random function , i actually used my code, which finds the root and it worked fine  , i also tested it in matlab and got the same answer as my root

Comment: Frankly, the OP's post has been so wildly edited by so many different people that it's impossible to tell what he really has.

Comment: I think its still clear i'm just trying to get it to output the function that you enter, but it get f = nan

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are not verbs.

Comment: yeah i didnt edit it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you are trying to define `f` as an *actual* mathematics function (in the direct way of doing it).  That definitely won't work.

But if you have a string, then `f` will output a string, ignoring the mathematics function.

Remember, unlike other programming languages, C++ is very...temperamental.

You can't assign a character to an `int` and vice versa.  But `string` can hold *anything* because it is only a piece of text.

Try using `getline`...just wait a sec and I'll go get my book..

*Edit:* Okay.  If you use `getline (cin, foo);`, where `foo` is defined as `string foo` and you include `<string>`, this should work. Is that what your coding originally looked like?

*Edit2:* You should still be able to use `stream` to convert from a string back and forth...but I'd need somebody more experienced than me to confirm that.

Comment: OK, no guarantee remember. BTW, `double` is for declaring a `double float` -- a float that's equal to 10 decimal places.  It can't handle a string or words...maybe that's where you're going wrong...?

Comment: thanks i got it to display , now i just need to convert it back to double so i can use it in my original numerical analysis code 
Thanks again once i get +15 rep i'll vote you up

Comment: Thank you! Glad it worked! :D You can still award your 'tick' btw, in case you didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an algebraic system.  While such things may exist, they are rather rare.  You'd have to look for a library to handle formulae in a general way, converting text representations into an executable (or interpretable) format at run time.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of X?  It may be that the number is so large that you get an over (or under) flow error which could explain why you get NaN.

I suggest you printout X as well and update the question.